# Допущена ли ошибка в синтаксисе, или дело в другом?

Tags: c#

На строчке:

```
if (lenght1 => 5) and (lenght1 <= 15)
```

Программа пишет: ожидалась ;

В чем ошибка?

```
int inputNum = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
List<string> forRhombus = new List<string> ();


switch (inputNum) 
{
    case 1:
    string a = "*";
    Console.WriteLine ("Введите нечетную длину стороны ромба от 5 до 15: ");
    int lenght1 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

    if (lenght1 => 5) and (lenght1 <= 15)
    {   
        for (int x = 0; x < lenght1; x++)
        {
            forRhombus.Add (" ");
        }
        if (lenght1 % 2 != 0)
        {   
            for (int y = 0; y < lenght1; y++)
        {

                    }
                }   
            }
            break;
```

Answer (score 5):

Допущена ошибка синтаксиса, так как нет оператора `and`.

Для логического "И" нужно использовать [`&&`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator)

Кроме этого все выражение нужно обернуть в круглые скобки.

А также ошибка в операторе ["больше или равно"](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/greater-than-equal-operator): `=>` нужно заменить на `>=`

В итоге получится:

```
if ((lenght1 >= 5) && (lenght1 <= 15))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((lenght1 >= 5) && (lenght1 <= 15))
```

Сначала всегда знак <> а потом =

Answer (score 1):

Вы не правильно построили синтаксис, правильно надо:

```
if(lenght1 >= 5 && lenght1 <= 15)
{
 //ваш код
}
```

Comment: Теперь пишет: не удалось преобразовать лямбда-выражение в тип "bool", так как он не является типом делегата

Comment: @Михаил прошу прощения, не посмотрел то как вы сравниваете, поправил как надо.